# Is the the statement is true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $V$ is a $m \times 1$ matrix with both $A$ and $V$ having rational entries and suppose the system $AX=V$ has a solution in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then the equation has a solution with rational entries.

Is the above statement true or false?

Comment: Yes. Moreover, $\dim_{\Bbb Q}\ker A=\dim_{\Bbb R}\ker A$ (since $\operatorname{rk} A$ is the size of a maximal minor with non-zero determinant), so the affine dimension of the space of solutions is the same. In the case of a unique solution, a handy-dandy way to see it is thanks to Cramer's formula. In the case of multiple solutions, it's basically because each step of Gauss' elimination algorithm preserves the field where the coefficients are.

Answer (score 2):

True. Rational numbers form a field albeit not closed under certain algebraic operations. However, you are not performing any of those operations (obtaining the roots of a polynomial) to solve this system of equations.

Comment: what is the concern of the field with the given statement>

Comment: Sorry, perhaps my answer was not clear. What I meant is that you are going to get a system of linear equations with operations +,-,x and /. Rationals are closed under all these so whatever solution you get will still be rational.

Comment: yes now i got hint. thanks

Comment: there exist real solutions with some irrational entries also from your comment am not getting anything to generalise